# How to know more details about a previous rollout revision using kubectl?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

There are commands given [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/cheatsheet/#updating-resources) which explain how to perform a rollback using `kubectl`. One that lists the previous versions of your deployment is:

`kubectl rollout history deployment/myDeployment`

This shows a list of previous versions based on their order and just their corresponding numbers. But how to know more details about them? It is hard to know which version I am rolling back to by just looking at a number.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use the revision flag to get more information:

> `kubectl rollout history deployment/<Deployment-name>  --revision=<revision-number>`

This will give you details about the Pod Template used in the specified revision number.

If you want the date on which the revision was deployed, use the -o yaml flag and check for `creationTimestamp`

> `kubectl rollout history deployment/<Deployment-name>  --revision=<revision-number>  -o yaml`

Comment: Thanks. It is strange that it doesn't give information about the date. Only the configurational details. Without knowing date/time it is hard to know which github commit/merge resulted in this particular revision.

Comment: `creationTimestamp` is the time when the `Deployment` itself was _created_, not when it was _changed_ via `apply`. Actually, I didn't find a timestamp for when it was _changed_, too.

Comment: `--revision` and `-o yaml|json` did not work together in `kubectl <= v1.25.0`, the output was of the current deployment not the one pointed to by `--revision` (see bug #111093). It was fixed [in this PR in kubernetes](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/111093). As of writing this you have to build kubectl from source to get the working version. For the next release I suppose this will be included.