# Getting the rollout times of a specific pod using rollout history using kubectl

Tags: kubectl

I'm looking for a way to get the deployment / rollout times of the previous deployments (and for bonus points a range of deployments) of my api

This guy tells me what the previous revisions are:

```
k rollout history deployment/api-v1

REVISION  CHANGE-CAUSE
29        <none>
30        <none>
31        <none>
32        <none>
33        <none>
34        <none>
```

But I've been playing around trying to get a rollout time with this either through jsonpath or without and have not been successful. Your help would be appreciated.

thanks

Comment: Can you try this command to get deployment / rollout times of the previous deployments:

Rollout history deployment/api-V1 -o wide

Comment: i don't think that's a valid command ... unable to match a printer suitable for the output format "wide", allowed formats are: go-template,go-template-file,json,jsonpath,jsonpath-as-json,jsonpath-file,name,template,templatefile,yaml

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to know more details about a previous rollout revision using kubectl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60300051/how-to-know-more-details-about-a-previous-rollout-revision-using-kubectl)

Comment: Did you a had time to check my comment? It helped you to solve your problem? If yes, Kindly let me know.

Comment: yes it did. when i look at the annotations and timestamp Inside it tells me the rollout time of each revision.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am glad that my comment helped to solve the issue. Posting it as an answer for everyone's benefit.

Can you try this command to get deployment / rollout times of the previous deployments:

**K rollout history deployment/api-v1**

**K rollout history deployment/api-v1 --revision=<revision_number>o yaml|grep creationtimestamp**

You can use the revision flag to get more information:

kubectl rollout history deployment/  --revision=

This will give you details about the Pod Template used in the specific revision number.

If you want the date on which the revision was deployed, use the -o yaml flag and check for creationTimestamp

kubectl rollout history deployment/  --revision=  -o yaml

For more information follow this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60300051) .

For more information about kubectl commands follow this [link](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#rollout) .

Comment: Parroting another comment: The `creationTimestamp` isn't when that revision was done, but when the resource was initially created. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60300051/how-to-know-more-details-about-a-previous-rollout-revision-using-kubectl#comment125115038_60300191